# Puppeteer - Using wildcard to retrieve correct element in webpage

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to fill out a form on a hotel website (https://www.marriott.com/default.mi) using Puppeteer.

Specifically, I am trying to type in DESTINATION box. When I right click the DESTINATION box -> inspect -> and `Copy selector` from Chrome inspect page it returns:

```
#\31 682277075343-search-destination
```

**Issue:** The numerical numbers BEFORE the "-search-destination" always change. e.g. `1682277075343` in id="1682277075343-search-destination"

**Question:**
How do I retrieve the DESTINATION search input box element using *wildcard* for my await page.type code to get around the random numerical string for id?

Or is there an easier way to retrieve and type into that box field?

---

Things I have tried:

```
await page.type([id^="-search-destination"], "Chicago, IL, USA")
```

```
await page.type([id="$-search-destination"], "Chicago, IL, USA")
```

But above returns error:

```
                if (selector.startsWith(prefix)) {
                             ^

TypeError: selector.startsWith is not a function
```

I tried searching based on class, based on ".search-field-box > input", based on "#edit-search-form > div > div..." but Puppeteer keeps saying it cannot find the element.

Comment: Did you try `$=` rather than `^=`? Usually, [browser-generated selectors are poor](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors).

Comment: `"[id^="-search-destination"]"` has a syntax error because the quotes are mismatched. JS thinks you're ending the string with the second `"`. Try `'[id$="-search-destination"]'`. `([id="$-search-destination"]` after your edit is also incorrect syntax because the quotes are missing entirely.

Comment: Hi @ggorlen, what you suggested returns ```                if (selector.startsWith(prefix)) {
                             ^

TypeError: selector.startsWith is not a function``` error

Comment: It works for me, so there must be something else wrong with your script. A [mcve] would be good. I'll post an answer anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a CSS attribute selector, `^=` anchors to the beginning of the string, but you want the end, so you can use `$=` instead. Here's an example:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.7.2

const url = "<Your URL>";
 
let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  await page.type('[id$="-search-destination"]', "Chicago, IL, USA");
  await page.screenshot({path: "test.png"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

That said, you might prefer a user-visible selector:

```js
const input = await page.waitForSelector('[placeholder*="Where next?"]');
await input.type("Chicago, IL, USA");
```

The site is heavy and slow so I'd probably block most of the external resources it's pulling down to speed this script up.

You probably want to run the search and detect when you're on the result page. Here's one way:

```js
const url = "<Your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua =
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  await page.type('[id$="-search-destination"]', "Chicago, IL, USA");
  await page.keyboard.press("Enter");
  await page.waitForSelector("text/View Rates");
  await page.screenshot({path: "test.png", fullPage: true});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```