# How to choose date range in calendar with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to fill out a form on a hotel website (https://www.marriott.com/default.mi), in particular, I want to select Aug 7 to Aug 10 2023 date in the website's calendar (note URL does not change so I have to manipulate DOM).

**Question:** After I click into the calendar (via `await page.click(".h-r-form-field-txt.search__calendar-value");`, how do I select date range?
[image]

Using `page.waitForSelector` also gave me an error:

```
        _Callback_error.set(this, new Errors_js_1.ProtocolError());
                                  ^

ProtocolError: Waiting for selector `[class$="search-dates-popup"]` failed: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Target closed
```

---

Code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const fs = require('fs/promises')

async function start(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.marriott.com/default.mi", {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});

    /**FILL OUT FORM*/ 
    // 1) Fill DESTINATION
    await page.type('[id$="-search-destination"]', "Chicago, IL, USA");
    // TODO: Need to press ENTER or something after putting in Chicago

    // 2) Fill Number of NIGHTS
    // click into the box first
    await page.click(".h-r-form-field-txt.search__calendar-value");

    // waitForSelector 
    page.waitForSelector('[class$="search-dates-popup"]');

    // TODO: Figure how to screenshot AFTER calendar is loaded
    await page.screenshot({ path: "test5_click.png" });
    // pick month and pick date

    await browser.close() 
}

start()
```

Comment: Showing a simple, complete runnable [mcve] is always helpful. Oftentimes, a single line leaves a lot of important debugging context out. For example, are you using `page.waitForSelector` to make sure these selectors are present first before clicking? BTW, an easier way to do this might be to use the query parameters of the URL so you don't have to touch the DOM at all.

Comment: `page.click(".h-r-form-field-txt search__calendar-value")` should probably be `page.click(".h-r-form-field-txt.search__calendar-value")`. When there are multiple class names on an element, you should join them together. Otherwise, a space means "search the children of this element". I suggest spending a bit of time on a basic CSS selector tutorial--it'll probably save you a lot of time, in light of this and the last question. Also, as mentioned in the last question, probably best to select by text in many cases, `page.click("text/Check In - Check Out");`.

Comment: The URL of the page doesn't change so I have to touch the DOM. Okay, I will watch basic CSS selector tutorial. Another question: How do I wait for the calendar to load completely after I click into the it?

Comment: Probably use `waitForSelector` for some selector or text that only shows up when the dialog appears. I noticed on some searches on this page, there was a URL that had all of the query parameters encoded but I lost it. If I have time I'll look around again.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Don't forget to use `await` before `page.waitForSelector('[class$="search-dates-popup"]')`. That should be enough to block until the popup is ready, although `'.search-dates-popup'` is better because it doesn't assume that the class is the last one and doesn't give a false positive for `foosearch-dates-popup`. Only use `class$=` when you need to allow for dynamic numbers and so forth, sort of a last resort. Then click the right arrow until `.DayPicker-Caption` has the text that matches the month you want, then click the date you want.

Comment: OP, please don't sabotage your post. The idea behind Stack Overflow is that the questions are left up as a reference for future visitors with the same problem. Think Wikipedia. If you remove the entire question, then the context is totally gone and my answer becomes irrelevant to anyone that needs these techniques in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76086775/puppeteer-using-wildcard-to-retrieve-correct-element-in-webpage/76087017#76087017) for context.

As described in comments, you can iterate over the months until you find one that matches your desired start date, then click the day you want and repeat the process again for the end month/day pair.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.7.2

const url = "<Your URL>";
const startMonth = "August";
const startDay = 7;
const endMonth = "August";
const endDay = 10;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua =
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  await page.setViewport({width: 800, height: 600});

  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  //await page.type('[id$="-search-destination"]', "Chicago, IL, USA");
  await page.click(".search__calendar-value");
  await page.waitForSelector(".search-dates-popup");

  const findMonth = async targetMonth => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      const month = await page.$eval(
        ".DayPicker-Month",
        el => el.textContent
      );
    
      if (month.includes(targetMonth)) {
        break;
      }
    
      await page.click('[aria-label="Next Month"]');
    }
  };

  const chooseDay = day => page.$$eval(
    ".DayPicker-Day-value",
    (els, day) => els.find(e => e.textContent.trim() === day).click(),
    String(day)
  );

  await findMonth(startMonth);
  await chooseDay(startDay);
  await findMonth(endMonth);
  await chooseDay(endDay);

  await page.screenshot({path: "test.png"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Be sure to always `await` every Puppeteer API call that returns a promise, which is most of them. [Not awaiting `page.waitForSelector` is a bug](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#forgetting-to-await-a-puppeteer-call).